# How do I include categorical covariates in Geogam analysis?

Tags: geospatial

I am trying to do an analysis using *Geogam* in r. The problem is that when I include categorical covariates, I get the following error:

> Error in while (t.df < 6) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

Any help to resolve this please.

Comment: Please include more of the code in question so others can have more of an understanding of what the issue could be

Comment: This is my code: geogam <- geoGAM(response = "pstatus",
                 covariates = c("hhsize", "hhagey", "edyears","ez","hhsex"),
                 coords = c("longnum", "latnum"),
                 data = rr,
                 offset = T,
                 non.stationary = F,
                 seed = 1,
                 validation.data = rr)